# sorting dataframe by string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe which looks like this:

```
Name  Net Worth
A     100M
B     200M
C     5M
D     40M
E     10B
F     2B
```

I would like to sort it by values in Net Worth column, what would be most optimal way to sort values lie this? M means million and B means billion so 10B would be the highest value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html), create new sorted `Series` and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) original:

```
d = {'M': '0'*6, 'B': '0'*9}
s = df['Net Worth'].replace(d, regex=True).astype(float).sort_values(ascending=False)
print (df.reindex(s.index))
  Name Net Worth
4    E       10B
5    F        2B
1    B      200M
0    A      100M
3    D       40M
2    C        5M
```

More general solution, if some `floats` are in data:

```
print (df)
  Name Net Worth
0    A         1
1    B      200M
2    C        5M
3    D       40M
4    E      1.0B
5    F        2B

#dict for multiple
d = {'M': 10**6, 'B': 10**9}
#all keys of dict separated by | (or)
k = '|'.join(d.keys())

#replace by dict
a = df['Net Worth'].replace(d, regex=True).astype(float)
#remove M,B
b = df['Net Worth'].replace([k], '', regex=True).astype(float)
#multiple together, sorts
s = a.mul(b).sort_values(ascending=False)
#reindex - get sorted original
print (df.reindex(s.index))
  Name Net Worth
5    F        2B
4    E      1.0B
1    B      200M
3    D       40M
2    C        5M
0    A         1
```

And another similar solution with [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
#dict for replace
_prefix = {'k': 1e3,    # kilo
           'M': 1e6,    # mega
           'B': 1e9,    # giga
}
#all keys of dict separated by | (or)
k = '|'.join(_prefix.keys())
#extract values to new df
df1 = df['Net Worth'].str.extract('(?P<a>[0-9.]*)(?P<b>' + k +')*', expand=True)
#convert numeric column to float
df1.a = df1.a.astype(float)
#map values by dictionary, replace NaN (no prefix) to 1
df1.b = df1.b.map(_prefix).fillna(1)
#multiple columns together
s = df1.a.mul(df1.b).sort_values(ascending=False)
print (s)
#sorting by reindexing
print (df.reindex(s.index))
  Name Net Worth
5    F        2B
4    E      1.0B
1    B      200M
3    D       40M
2    C        5M
0    A         1
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one questions how regex=True works in this case? Is it simiar to `df.str.replace()`?

Comment: Yes, it is similar, but better working with `dict`. And if need replace by substring, need `regex=True`